# Communicate between docker-compose and dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuget

I'm stuck on this for a couple of days.

I'm trying to use a local NuGet server (using BaGet) as part of my deployment using docker.
When adding the the NuGet server to my docker-compose file, the Dockerfile build process can't seem to access it.

As far as I understand, each docker-compose folder gets its own network and other docker composes and standalone containers cant access this network.

But when .NET Dockerfile is running, its launching a standalone container (using the FROM keyword), which doesn't has access to my NuGet server (docker-compose isolated network).

docker-compose.yml :

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  nugetlocal:
    image: loicsharma/baget:latest
    container_name: nuget-server
    environment:
      - Storage__Type=FileSystem
      - Storage__Path=/var/baget/packages
      - Database__Type=Sqlite
      - Database__ConnectionString=Data Source=/var/baget/baget.db
      - Search__Type=Database
    ports:
      - "5555:80"
    volumes:
      - ./baget/baget-data:/var/baget

  identity.api:
    build:
      context: ../api/identity-service
      dockerfile: /src/Identity.Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - nuget-server
```

dockerfile:

```yaml
#Running a standalone container right there.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
#...
COPY ["src/Identity.Api/Identity.Api.csproj", "src/Identity.Api/"]
#Here im adding the local nuget packgage sources
RUN dotnet nuget add source http://nugetlocal/v3/index.json -n local.nuget
RUN dotnet restore "src/Identity.Api/Identity.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Identity.Api"
#...
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.Api.dll"]
```

I tried manually defining networks, linking,exposing, and what not.
I also tried running the NuGet as a standalone server and set the IP of the NuGet machine in the Dockerfile (DNS wont work on default network interface) and it actually worked, 
but I would really prefer to work with DNS here and with the least amount of scripts I can (stick to compose files).

Thanks !

Comment: For a couple of reasons, a Dockerfile can't make calls out to other Compose services.  Can you run the package repository somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess I can run it ok the host machine and use localhost as the source. I will update on that.

Comment: As elsewhere in Docker, `localhost` won't work (it will refer to a temporary container being used by the `RUN` command) but if `host.docker.internal` works in your (MacOS or Windows) environment it should work here.